# How to export an interactive dashboard app into a html standalone file to embed it to your website?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, data-visualization, html-encode

So I made an interactive dashboard using plotly in python. I deployed the app and converted the visualization plots to the static html files. But what if I want to embed the whole dashboard including the non-static components too. My goal is to develop a simple interactive dashboard which takes csv as input and visualizes the data in couple of lines in text, which can be later embedded as a whole to a pre-existing xml/html page.like this:
[image]

I have some interactive filters for the end-user using callbacks:

```
@app.callback(
Output(component_id='release_choice', component_property='options'),
[Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value')])

def get_options(Tech_choice):
    dff = df[df.Technology == Tech_choice]
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dff['SystemRelease'].unique()]

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value'),
    [Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='options')])
def get_values(release_choice):
    return [k['value'] for k in release_choice][1]

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='date_choice', component_property='start_date'),
    Output(component_id='date_choice', component_property='end_date')],
    [Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value')])
def get_options(date_choice):
    dff = df[df.date2 == date_choice]
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dff['date2']]


@app.callback(Output(component_id='my-graph', component_property='figure'),
              [Input(component_id='release_choice', component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='Tech_choice', component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='date_choice', component_property='start_date'),
              Input(component_id='date_choice', component_property='end_date')], )
```

I made a similar dash using pandas and plotly which looks like this:
[image]

I used fig.write_image to get the html file but again its just static. So what are your recommendations? I think plotly will not do the desired job. What else can I use in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use iframe tag of html:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" title="W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials"></iframe>
```

just replace the "src" with your website's URL, in that manner you'll get your plotly website embedded in any other HTML page. The dynamic elements will still work.

Comment: ty for the answer! So just to make sure I get it, this will auto-generate the entire dashboard to the website dynamically? It will be like fig.write_image but with all of the dynamic components of the plotly dashboard too? Like I can specify the deployed dashboard as a separate html document inside my website?

Comment: iframe appends all the html ( including all the functionality ) to the new website.

For example there are two websites,
Website 1 and Website 2

For some reasons I want to use website 1 in Website 2
so what I can do is I can insert it as an iframe in Website 2. If you go to developer tools you'll see the entire HTML code of website 1 ( in your case plotly ) will be imported to your website.

Comment: Thankyou so much. It makes complete sense and serves for a part of my work. But is there any way that the dashboard can also be generated to "static" XML as this needs to be also converted to PDF and only xml is accepted there, not html.